# How to get get all the data from table and if same value repeated in one column that row should count once?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

[leave_request table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNa8A.png)in my table emp_id column contains duplicate data 3 times. i want to select all the data from the table and the duplicate data to count as once. here i am providing the screenshot of my table structure

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ...`

Comment: your table's leave no is different - how you want that to be shown

Comment: @fa06 i want only id , emp_id and emp_name columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below -

```
select max(id),emp_id, emp_name
from tablename
group by emp_id, emp_name
```